# Given a homogeneous system, what can we say about a similar but nonhomogeneous system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Alright, so we have a homogeneous system of 8 equations in 10 variables (an 8 x 10 matrix, let's call it A). We have found two solutions that are not multiples of each other (lets call them a and b), and every other solution is a linear combination of them. Can you be certain that any nonhomogeneous equation with the same coefficients has a solution?

I want to say yes, but I'm not sure why. Here's the stuff I know:

- Our solution for the homogeneous system is span{a, b}.
- Since there are free variables/the null space is not just 0 we know there are nontrivial solutions.
- Dim(Null(A))=2

Comment: should be Dim(Null($A$))${}=2$, right?

Comment: Do you know a criterion for when any nonhomogeneous equation has a solution? Something related to the rank of $A$, perhaps?

Comment: I know that if the rank=n there is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that it's an 8x10 matrix and that dim Nul A is 2. 
Here we have n = 10. The rank-nullity theorem says that rank A + dim Nul A = n, so rank A must be 8. In other words, there are 8 pivot columns.

Since your matrix has 8 rows, every row has a pivot, and therefore every solution in  $\mathbb{R^8}$ can be represented as a linear combination of the columns.

The general solution of A**x** = **b** can be represented by

(*v* + linear combinations of solutions to the homogeneous equations)

where *v* is the particular solution to the nonhomogeneous equation. So yes, a nonhomogeneous equation with the same coefficients has a solution.